Who should the moderators be? [Nomination]
Since the other "Who should the moderators be" question turned out to be more of a discussion about what makes a good moderator I thought that we'd start this topic that is just for nominating and voting.
Each answer here should be in the format below. The name of the person is also a link to his/her profile. Votes determine who we'd like to see as moderators. It is OK to nominate yourself.

Jane Doe
This is a little text about Jane Doe. What we know about her, why she would be suitable as a moderator. Just a few lines, not a novel.

Is the process as simple as the top M users according to answer score at a specific date/time will be selected as the M moderators?

No, it's not that simple. "Shortly after the public beta starts (1-2 weeks, generally), the Community team chooses 3 pro tem moderators. They're selected (versus elected) based on a number of factors, one of which is community input from a "Who should the moderators be?" meta post—assuming one exists." See this question: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-were-the-initial-moderators-for-bitcoin-stack-exchange-chosen

David Schwartz
Very active during private beta, has lots of high vote answers. Frequent editor. Active here on meta. Also an active member of a number of other StackExchange sites.

David Perry
He has been very active during the private beta, has good answers and questions and wants to be a moderator according to the discussion thread. He has also been active here at meta so he seems to care about the site.

nmat
Very active during private beta. Active here on meta and also on a few other StackExchange sites. Very frequent voter.

D.H.
He may not be the user with the greatest reputation, but he has been fairly active on the site. Besides asking and answering questions, he frequently edits other users' posts to add tags and improve readability. He is also very active here at meta with 7 questions asked and 300+ reputation.

eMansipater
Has been helping Bitcoin newcomers for a while now, and is an active StackExchange user.

If anyone comes up with a better description, feel free to edit.
